# How do I focus an input when I click a button with JavaScript alone

Tags: javascript, input, focus, buttonclick

Let's say I have an input with an id

```
<input type="text" id="inPut">
```

and a button

```
<button onclick="myFunc()"></button>
```

How do I write a function (with simple javascript) such that onclick of the button, the input is focused?

Answer (score 1):

```
const myFunc = () => {
   const input = document.getElementById("inPut");
   input.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic solution...

But you could use the focus method...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus

```
function myFunc() {
  document.getElementById("inPut").focus();
}
```